# Unable to send special symbols in array keys using $http POST method in AngularJS

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs

Unable to send special symbols in array keys using $http POST method in AngularJS

Here is my AngularJS Code:

```
var httpHeader = {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;" }
};
var postData = { 'user_id !=': 1 };
$http.post("http://localhost/api/view/country", $httpParamSerializer(postData), httpHeader)
.then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
});
```

in PHP when i do:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

it shows:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

it should be like:

```
array(1) {
  [user_id !=]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

When i send it without "!=" it works fine. What should i do to sort out this? Thanks

Comment: Working right? https://eval.in/578519

Comment: https://eval.in/578520

Comment: Nice to see that, but i don't know why its not working in my case, let me add my code in the question

Comment: Perhaps an old version of PHP?

Comment: show var_dump($_POST);

Comment: var_dump($_POST) says
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
I have edited question with more code, please review. thanks

Comment: say `alert($httpParamSerializer(postData))` before post

Comment: yes, its showing exactly what need to be sent, but in PHP it won't work

Comment: @splash58 can you help me in that please

Comment: @Punit i can't reproduce your problem. Such script executed om my server shows desired result - https://eval.in/578561

Answer (score 0):

If you use associative array and as in your case pass key as String it will work normal
i don't know  why it is create

```
$arr[0] = 1;
```

[Working demo](https://eval.in/578530)

Comment: I am passing this array through POST method, with $.param() method

Comment: you can use **encodeURI()** javascript native function to post special characters . [link] (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)

OR **encodeURIComponent()**

Comment: I have edited question with more code, please review. thanks

Comment: for better explanation i have added new question, please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497000/unable-to-send-special-symbols-in-array-keys-using-http-post-method-in-angularj

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr["user_id !="] = 1;

// Print all the elements of $arr
print_r($arr);

echo '<br/>'.$arr["user_id !="] ;
```

Run the above code. I think "user_id !=" is not a problem of index name as it works fine.

Comment: Yes but i am passing it through POST method, AJAX call

Comment: @Punit How do you pass your data using AJAX. Would you please share your code, so that it will be easy to find out the problem

Comment: I have edited question as you suggested, please review. thanks

Comment: for better explanation i have added new question, please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497000/unable-to-send-special-symbols-in-array-keys-using-http-post-method-in-angularj